# How do I trigger flyout menu item when a key/letter is pressed while the flyout is open like in MS Office apps?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

When user right clicks an item to show the context menu, I want them to be able to just press a key (even without a modifier) in their keyboard to activate certain menus (like in Office apps).

I've looked at access keys and keyboard accelerators but they don't seem to be the right API since they require a modifier to be held.

Thank you.

Comment: try `PreviewKeyDown` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.previewkeydown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `PreviewKeyDown` event handler to current window content when `MenuFlyout` opened. Invoke matching method in the `PreviewKeyDown` event handler  when specific `VirtualKey` pressed. Then remove `PreviewKeyDown` event handler when MenuFlyout closed to avoid false triggering.

```
<Button Content="Edit Options" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Button.Flyout >
        <MenuFlyout Opened="MenuFlyout_Opened" Closed="MenuFlyout_Closed" >
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Share">
                <MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
                    <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE72D;"/>
                </MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
            </MenuFlyoutItem>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Copy"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete"/>
            <MenuFlyoutSeparator/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Rename"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Select"/>
        </MenuFlyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

**Code behind**

```
private void MenuFlyout_Opened(object sender, object e)
{
    Window.Current.Content.PreviewKeyDown += Content_PreviewKeyDown;
}
private void MenuFlyout_Closed(object sender, object e)
{
    Window.Current.Content.PreviewKeyDown -= Content_PreviewKeyDown;
}
private void Content_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if(e.Key == VirtualKey.D)
    {
        //delete current item
    }
}
```